# Matrix as dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy

I've just started using `numpy` and its `matrix` module (very very useful!), and I wanted to use a matrix object as the key of a dictionary, so I checked if `matrix` had the `__hash__` method implemented:

```
>>> from numpy import matrix
>>> hasattr(matrix, '__hash__')
True
```

And it does! Nice, so it means that it can be the key of a dictionary:

```
>>> m1 = matrix('1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9')
>>> m1
matrix([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]])
>>> m2 = matrix('1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1')
>>> m2
matrix([[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]])
>>> matrix_dict = {m1: 'first', m2: 'second'}
```

Worked! Now, let's keep testing:

```
>>> matrix_dict[m1]
'first'
>>> matrix_dict[matrix('1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: matrix([[1, 2, 3],
                  [4, 5, 6],
                  [7, 8, 9]])
```

What? So, it works for the same matrix, but it doesn't work for another matrix with the exact same content? Let's see what `__hash__` returns:

```
>>> hash(m1)
2777620
>>> same_as_m = matrix('1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9')
>>> hash(same_as_m)
-9223372036851998151
>>> hash(matrix('1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9')) # same as m too
2777665
```

So, the `__hash__` method of the `matrix` from `numpy` returns different values for the same `matrix`.

Is this right? So, does it means that it cannot be used as a dictionary key? And if it can't be used, why does it have `__hash__` implemented?

Comment: Python objects are hashable by default - you have to disable it for unhashable classes. Could be just an omission on the part of `numpy`.

Comment: A matrix is an ndarray underneath, and they are also hashable by default - I assume you'd have the same problem using them too.

Comment: @jozzas, I was surprised it was possible to use a matrix as a dictionary key because I know that ndarrays cannot be used as keys and matrix is a subclasses of ndarray

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be wrong to use a mutable object as a key of a dictionary because its hash should change as soon as you change the data, but the value used on insertion will be kept.

On my tests, numpy at Python 3.2.2 raise a TypeError:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'matrix'
```

But on Python 2.7 it still allows hashing but the hash value never changes when you change data, so it is pretty useless as dictionary key because many `matrix` objects being added to the dictionary having the same hash will degrade the hash table so insertion will be `O(n^2)` instead of `O(1)`.

Maybe they didn't remove the hash value to avoid breaking some API on Python 2.x, but do not rely on it!