# Python: mapping numpy matrices to matrices

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, matrix

I need some construction like:

```
from numpy import *

myDict = {
    matrix([ 0,0,0 ]): matrix([ 0,0,0 ]),
    matrix([ 0,0,1 ]): matrix([ 0,1,0 ]),
    matrix([ 0,1,0 ]): matrix([ 0,1,1 ]),
    matrix([ 0,1,1 ]): matrix([ 1,0,0 ]),
    matrix([ 1,0,0 ]): matrix([ 1,0,1 ]),
    matrix([ 1,0,1 ]): matrix([ 1,1,0 ]),
    matrix([ 1,1,0 ]): matrix([ 0,0,1 ]),
    matrix([ 1,1,1 ]): matrix([ 1,1,1 ]),
}
```

But, when I call **myDict[matrix([ 0,1,1 ])]** it rise a KeyError.
So, how to implement mapping of matrices into matrices in Python?

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813226/matrix-as-dictionary-key ?

Comment: How do you create `myDict`? `typeError: unhashable type: 'matrix'`

Comment: @MikeMüller, I have "Python 2.7.10" and it let me did that.

Comment: @Merlin1896, I just need some easy solution, maybe not dict, but some else.

Comment: This is all covered in the original question linked above. Mutable objects, such as numpy arrays or matrices, are essentially useless as dictionary keys, since their hash values don't change even when the data contained within them does. For this reason, Python3 does not allow them to be used as dictionary keys, although some older versions of Python2 still do.

Comment: Your matrices look rather like vectors and additionally only contain zeros and ones. Is this a coincidence? If not, you could use the sequence of zeros and ones and interpret it as the bit sequence of an integer. Than you could index you matrix by this integer.