# Option to replace the matrix key return error in dictionary using python

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix

I have a list of matrix and I would like to print the value for that key. This is the code:

```
list1=np.matrix([[ 0.],[ 1.]]),np.matrix([[ 1.],[ 0.]]),np.matrix([[ 1.],[ 0.]])
print (list1)
dictionary = { np.matrix([[ 0.],[ 1.]]): '1' , np.matrix([[ 1.],[ 0.]]):'0'}
output=[dictionary[i] for i in list1]
```

The output shows like this:

```
(matrix([[ 0.],
        [ 1.]]), 
 matrix([[ 1.],
        [ 0.]]), 
 matrix([[ 1.],
        [ 0.]]))
dictionary = { np.matrix([[ 0.],[ 1.]]): '1' , np.matrix([[ 1.],[ 0.]]):'0'}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'matrix'
```

Supposedly, the output shows like this:

```
1, 0, 0
```

Since the matrix can not be used as the key in dictionary, is there any way to assign the value for the list of matrix?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix as dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813226/matrix-as-dictionary-key)

Comment: you can reverse the role. use matrix as values instead of keys. Depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrices cannot be used as keys for dictionaries. If you want to know more about dictionary keys, check out [this site](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys). Even though it has a `__hash__`, mutable objects should not be used as hashes, as if you change the value, then you will most likely get `KeyError`.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813226/matrix-as-dictionary-key), hash method for numpy matrix does not satisfy one of the basic condition of hash:

`for all i1, i2, if hash(i1) != hash(i2), then i1 != i2`

However, when I tried using hash(np.matrix('1 2; 3 4)), I got :

```
>>> from numpy import matrix
>>> hasattr(matrix,'__hash__')
True
>>> hash(matrix('1 2; 3 4'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'matrix'
```

One possible solution (which may or may not work for all cases):

```
>>> l = matrix([[0.],[1.]]),matrix([[ 1.],[ 0.]]),matrix([[ 1.],[ 0.]])
>>>dict = {str(matrix([[ 0.],[ 1.]])): '1' ,str(matrix([[ 1.],[ 0.]])):'0'}
>>> output = [dict[str(i)] for i in l]
>>> output
['1', '0', '0']
```

String are hashable, unlike matrix

Comment: In your opinion, is there any ways to assign the value for the list of matrix instead of using dictionary key?

Comment: Yes. This is the good solution.
Thank you so much.
Highly appreciated.